Angular Material Nested mat-tab-group on "child" default mat-tab is not marked as active (Angular version: 9.0.1, Angular Material version 9.2.4)
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
      <mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
          <mat-tab label="Tab 1">sub tab 1 Content</mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="Tab 2">sub tab 2 Content</mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

enter image description here
I am expecting sub tab 1 by default should be active

not reproducible stackblitz
